# Having trouble remotely connecting to MariaDB on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mariadb

Trying to get some experience using AWS for MariaDB/MySQL.  I have the instance setup and working when I SSH into the EC2 instance.  However I want to be able to use a remote client like Navicat from my office static IP address.

So far I've created an AWS security group to allow TCP on 22 and 3306 from my office IP address.

I've edited my.cnf and changed the bind address to 0.0.0.0

I've created a user 'user'@'my.ip.address' and granted permissions for that user on a test database.

The EC2 is running Debian so the other tips about iptables don't seem to apply.

What else am I missing to allow Navicat to connect to the db?  For hostname/IP in Navicat "public dns" name as shown in my EC2 instance and the username & password I created for the database user.

Comment: Can you ssh into EC2 from your office computer?

Comment: Yes, using the Amazon provided PEM key converted to a Putty PPK with PuttyGen.  I've tried using both key types in Navicat and MySQL Workbench 6.3 to route the connection to the db through SSH but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED.  Originally I went into AWS --> EC2 --> Network & Security --> Security Groups and created a new group that permitted 3306 from my office static IP.

However, when I AWS --> EC2 --> Instances and examined the bottom frame on the screen for Description, the new group I created wasn't applied to this instance.  Instead it was just the default "MariaDB 10-1 on Debian 8-10-1-10-AutogenByAWSMP".  I could not figure out how to add my new security group ID to this instance, but I did add an inbound rule for port 3306 to the "MariaDB 10-1 on Debian 8-10-1-10-AutogenByAWSMP" rule and that allowed the connection.